# could not optimize @tailrec annotated method loop: it contains a recursive call not in tail position

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I have the following recursive function which I want to use tail recursion on it. But compiler complains about my implementation with this error:`Error:(79, 7) could not optimize @tailrec annotated method loop: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
      n match {
      ^`

is it because of for loop that it assumes it's  not in tail position?

```
def dsl[N,E](qNodes:QNodeLike[N,E]*) = {
    val markers = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, N]
    @tailrec
    def loop(n:QNodeLike[N,E]):Unit = {
      n match {
        case QNode(head, kids:Seq[HalfEdgeLike[E,N]]) => {

          for(kid <- kids){
            kid match {
              case EmptyHalfEdge() =>
              case HalfEdge(e, n) => loop(n)
            }
          }
        }

        case QNodeMarker(head, marker, kids:Seq[HalfEdgeLike[E,N]]) => {
          markers.update(marker,head)
          for(kid <- kids){
            kid match {
              case EmptyHalfEdge() =>
              case HalfEdge(e, n) => loop(n)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    loop(qNodes.head)
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's right.  To make it tail recursive, you should use an explicit accumulator which is passed into the recursion.

However, unless you have *very* deep and narrow trees, you are unlikely to need tail recursive optimization, as the run time will grow very large well before you end up with a stack overflow.

Here's a rough idea of how to make it tail optimized:

```
@tailrec
def loop(n:List[QNodeLike[N,E]]):Unit = {
  n match {
    case QNode(head, kids:Seq[HalfEdgeLike[E,N]]) :: rem => {
      kids match {
        case Nil =>
        case EmptyHalfEdge() :: rem2 => loop(rem2 ::: rem)
        case HalfEdge(e, n) :: rem2 => loop(n :: rem2 ::: rem)
      }
    }

    case QNodeMarker(head, marker, kids:Seq[HalfEdgeLike[E,N]]) :: rem => {
      markers.update(marker,head)
      kids match {
        case Nil =>
        case EmptyHalfEdge() :: rem2 => loop(rem2 ::: rem)
        case HalfEdge(e, n) :: rem2 => loop(n :: rem2 ::: rem)
      }
    }

    case Nil =>
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but about your solution: type of rem2 is a Seq[HaldEdgeLike[N,E]] not SeqpQNodeLike[N,E]]

Comment: ah.. HalfEdgeLike isn't a subtype of QNodeLike?  That makes it a little messier, but you can apply the same principles.  Simply pass two arguments `edgeLikeRem` and `nodeLikeRem` and treat them separately.

Comment: alternatively, unroll two levels of the recursion into one function, so that you extract all the `QNodeLike`s in all the `HalfEdges` of your QNode in one stack frame, and thus only pass `QNodeLike`s in the accumulator

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is because of the loop. The result of a tailrec funtion has to be the result of the recursive call. In your case the result is the result of the for statement.